# Using a struct from one header, within a struct of another

Tags: c++, struct, header-files

I have a homework assignment where I need to create a binary tree, and within each node point to a linked list.

I have my linkedList program working from a previous assignment. However within my binary tree struct, I would like to access the struct from linked list.

Here's an example of what I am talking about.

**BinaryTree.h**

```
#ifndef BinaryTree_h
#define BinaryTree_h

#include <iostream>    

using namespace std;    

struct bnode {
    bnode * lChild;
    bnode * rChild;
    string word;

    lnode * lineList; // <--------- This is what I would like to accomplish


};
```

**LinkedList.h**

```
#ifndef LinkedList_h
#define LinkedList_h

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct lnode {
    lnode * prev;
    int data;
    void *pointerData;
    lnode * next;

};
```

Comment: **Do not** put `using namespace std;` in headers, **ever.** Anyone who includes that header will get the entire `std` namespace dumped into the global namespace, whether they want it or not.

Comment: @cdhowie Noted, Thank you!

Comment: you need to include `LinkedList.h` in `BinaryTree.h`. (Why it is named `linkedlist.h`?)

Comment: @appleapple I've tried that, it still says "lnode is undefined" I have 5 files, LinkedList.h LinkedList.cpp BinaryTree.h BinaryTree.cpp and Main. LinkedList.h is where I define my struct which is why I want to use it in BinaryTree.h where I define my BinaryTree struct

Comment: @GreenFerret95 It should not give the error. But you can try forward declaration.

Comment: Use forward declaration. `struct lnode; struct bnode { ... };`. Lookup the term in your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. add `#include "LinkedList.h"` to `BinaryTree.h`:

   ```
   #ifndef BinaryTree_h
   #define BinaryTree_h

   #include <iostream>    
   #include "LinkedList.h" // <-- here

   struct bnode {
       bnode * lChild;
       bnode * rChild;
       std::string word;

       lnode * lineList;
   };

   #endif
   ```
2. since the `lineList` member is just a pointer, you can (and should) forward declare the `lnode` type without having to fully define it:

   ```
   #ifndef BinaryTree_h
   #define BinaryTree_h

   #include <iostream>    

   struct lnode; // <-- here

   struct bnode {
       bnode * lChild;
       bnode * rChild;
       std::string word;

       lnode * lineList;
   };

   #endif
   ```

In the latter case, you would still need to use `#include "LinkedList.h"` in any source files that need to access the content of the `lineList` member.